# What physical properties are invariant under relativistic transformation?

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, covariance, invariants

Most of the familiar physical properties vary according to the relativistic observer's reference frame - speed, mass, energy, time, length, etc. Which properties remain invariant, so everybody will always measure the same value?

Electric and colour charges appear to be. Width, orthogonal to any resultant gravitational/velocity vector, appears to be. Causality is in practice, although there is some debate over the niceties of interactions with entangled states. Is this list correct, and are there any others?

(Possibly relevant; [This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/595770/) asks about "objects" rather than properties in general, but has not been answered yet)

Comment: Mass do not change in relativity rather it is the momentum $\gamma p$ conjugate to position $x$ coordinate of an object which changes. Note that all quantities which are invariant under relativistic transformation are tensor quantities.

Comment: @KP99 Many discussions distinguish "relativistic mass" from "rest mass". For example Britannica gives the definition "*Relativistic mass*, in the special theory of relativity, the mass that is assigned to a body in motion". In this commonly-used sense, mass is indeed variable.

Comment: @GuyInchbald The concept of relativistic mass is obsolete. We know for a fact now that mass is not variable but is a relativistic constant. What changes is the energy of the particle which is, in fact, non a relativistic invariant. Have a look at this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_shell_and_off_shell).

Comment: @DavideMorgante That article does not mention relativistic mass as such, and is also poorly-cited. Searching for "Relativistic mass" actually takes you to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_special_relativity#Relativistic_mass which is well-cited and makes no mention of obsolescence. Whatever the philosophical and ontological semantic, I use the term as it is commonly understood. After all, this is the physics SE not the philosophy one.

Comment: @GuyInchbald The relevancy of the cited wikipedia page on the mass-shell relation is in the fact that $p^2$ is a relativistic invariant by construction. Moreover, fore real particles $p^2=m^2$ which is the mass of the particle, the only relevant mass.

Comment: @DavideMorgante You appear to be insisting that the invariant mass (aka rest mass) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_mass is the only meaning allowed for "mass". I can find no support for that claim anywhere, especially not on Wikipedia. But mentioning invariant mass and the momentum relation could be a useful part of any answer.